# Passing argument into const char *

Tags: c++, mysql

I want to make mysql query it look like this:

```
SELECT name FROM AUTHORS where name LIKE %[here argument]%
```

I search for solution and i find putting arg in "+[arg]+" like this;

```
  const char * author = getString("Author: ", 100).c_str();
  // res type MYSQL_RES* res
  res = exec_query(conn, "select name from authors where name like '%"+author+"%'");
```

But i gives me an error:

> expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Comment: You can `+` concatenate objects of type `std::string` but not c-style strings.

Comment: is it an option to do this with char

Comment: C++ is not the kind of language you can guess your way through.  Adding a pointer to a string literal has no meaning.  `+` does not do what you are imagining it does.

Comment: That question tells me that maybe you would benefit from [getting a decent book and learn the basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/430766) before proceeding.

Comment: Are you a Java programmer, by any chance?  What you are doing (using `+`) looks llike an attempt to use something that works in Java (or similar languages), but does not work in C++.  If this is the case, do not use Java (or any other language) as a model in writing C++ code.  All you will wind up with is 1) Buggy code, 2) Inefficient code, 3) Code that looks weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: Correction to the above: `+` works exactly as you expect it to, but only if you use it on the correct types. the semantics around `char *` date back about 50 years and made pretty good sense at the time.

Comment: BTW, care with string concatenation to build query, see [xkcd: exploits of mom](https://xkcd.com/327/). Look for *'bind parameters'*.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems with your code:

- you are storing a *dangling pointer* in `author`
- you are trying to concatenate multiple `const char*` pointers.

Change your code to treat `author` and your concatenated SQL as `std::string` instead.  You can use `std::string::c_str()` when passing the final SQL string to mysql, eg:

```
std::string author = getString("Author: ", 100);
// res type MYSQL_RES* res
std::string sql = "select name from authors where name like '%"+author+"%'";
res = exec_query(conn, sql.c_str());
```

Do be aware that the code above is subject to SQL Injection attacks. You really should be using a *parameterized query* instead.

Comment: The last paragraph is, or at least closely related to, the [Saga of Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)